# Typescript support for onsenUI

Tags: angularjs, typescript, onsen-ui

Simple question,

is there or will there by Typescript support for thhe onsenUI framework, for example to use the

```
ons.ready(function() {..}
```

stuff in TypeScript?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see definition files on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/) yet.

But note: you can easily make them yourself! For example with your code as an example:

```
interface OnsStatic {
    ready: Function;
}
declare var ons: OnsStatic;
```

You can find lots of examples here: [TypeScript wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing%20Definition%20Files)